# Audience Mismatch and invalid Authorization Token

Tags: react-native, oauth, cloudfoundry-uaa, appauth

I'm trying to get an Authorization Code in a react-native Application that uses react-native-app-auth from an SAP Cloudfoundry Endpoint.

This is the Config-format I am passing and which is working for other OAuth Providers(different than Cloudfoundry).

```
{
    clientId: <CLIENT_ID>,
    redirectUrl: <CLIENT_ID>',
    serviceConfiguration: {
      authorizationEndpoint: <ENDPOINTURL>...com/oauth2/api/v1/token,
      tokenEndpoint: <ENDPOINTURL>...com/oauth2/api/v1/authorize
    },
    scopes: ['uaa.user'],
}
```

I debugged the response and it comes back with accessToken, which seems to be invalid when I test it manually in Postman.

[image]

When debugging other Oauth Providers i dont get back an ID-Token at all and directly receive an access Token.

The endpoint itself works in postman with the same settings and gives me back an valid Token.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When debugging other Oauth Providers i dont get back an ID-Token at
> all and directly receive an access Token.

`id_token` is part of OpenID Connect. In first response there are three scopes and not just your `uaa.user` scope. It seems that `openid` is set to default scope in that provider so you are receiving `id_token` as well.

> I debugged the response and it comes back with accessToken, which seems to be invalid when I test it manually in Postman.

Why do you think accessToken is invalid?